# Android phone bahving strangely after passing metal detector

Tags: cyanogenmod, oneplus-one, system-freeze

Phone is Oneplus One running Cyanogenmod (usure about the version but it should be the latest released to OpOs)

It all started after a metal detector scan - the phone would work for 20-30 seconds fine and then the screen would freeze indefinitely. Upon restart you could see the same behaviour. Once I was back home I plugged it to my laptop to try to retrieve some of the data and noticed that while connected the phone was absolutely fine.

This led me to believe the issue is software related so I did a factory reset. Unfortunately, after that the issue remained so I decided to try to flash the ROM. Started by turning off my phone so I can go into the fastboot menu but now after turning it off it won't turn back on.

I'm certain that it isn't a battery issue but I'm running out of options. Neither power + vol up or power + vol down work at the moment and connecting it to the laptop does nothing.

Any suggestions what to do next?

Comment: What makes you think that it is not a battery issue? Problems that occur only when the device is unplugged are a strong indicator for battery issues. Try a power supply that only charges the phone. If the problems do not appears when charging, most likely the cause it is dying battery.

Comment: Because after freezing, I could restart it and it would start with the same battery percentage before freezing again. Also currently it doesn't charge after plugging it to anything at all.

Comment: Sounds like a faulty sensor... As soon as you requested access to the Metal Detector ( Magnetic Field Sensor ) It caused a Short Circuit that results in the power failure..... However if you are talking about a Physical Metal Detector like at an Airport or secure building, Then that is an obvious problem caused from the Frequency of the Metal Detector... Metal Detectors pump out a frequency and listen for the returning frequency, The returning frequency is different depending on the type and size of an object .. So the computer analysis is based on something similar to Sonar Beaconing.

Comment: I can not imagine that the frequency of a Metal Detector would cause a hardware issue on your device, however it is possible ! ...